# How to fetch push notifications when app is inactive ios swift3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am able to fetch push notifications when app is in open. but when My iOS native app is in inactive notifications are not triggering.
I shared my source code also. could anyone guide me how to do this task?

```
extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
  // [START refresh_token]
  func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")
    let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
  }

  func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
    //creating the notification content
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.userInfo = ["title": remoteMessage.appData["title"] as Any]
    content.subtitle = (content.userInfo["title"] as? String)!
    // content.body = (content.userInfo["message"] as? String)!
    content.badge = 1
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
    //getting the notification trigger
    //it will be called after 5 seconds
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 3, repeats: false)
    //getting the notification request
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "SimplifiedIOSNotification", content: content, trigger: trigger)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    //adding the notification to notification center
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by inactive? Do you put it in background or do you kill it manually. If you kill it, you won't receive push notifications anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform the following steps:

**Register for Push Notifications:**

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        setupNotifications(application)

        return true
    }

    func setupNotifications(_ application: UIApplication) {

        let center  = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.delegate = self

        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.sound, .alert, .badge]) { (granted, error) in }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        print("Notifications registration succeeded!")
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Notifications registration failed!")
    }

}
```

2) **The Delegate Methods**

```
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

        //Notification message clicked
    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,  willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (_ options:   UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }
}
```